# FAQ: Frequently Asked Questions and Reference Answers

Tags: discussion, faq, questions

Inspired by [this](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions), here is a list of frequently asked questions grouped by topic:

Here are some provisional categories:

- [What is Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/432/820)
- [Getting Started](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/820)
- [Mining (Proof of Work)](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/434/820)
- [Proof of Stake](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/435/820)
- [Contract Development](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/436/820)
- [Clients and User Inferace / Experience](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/437/820)
- [Testing / Contract Deployment](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/438/820)
- [Systems built with/on/around the Ethereum platform](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/439/820)

Please add/remove/re-order questions as you see fit...

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  Not much thoughts yet on what the categories could be.

Comment: Here is a [query for popular questions ordered by views](https://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/483849/top-10k-questions-by-view-count-questions-only), and here is a [list of highest voted questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).

Comment: Thanks for your work, @atomh33ls, I really appreciate this. With the recent influx of new users, I decided to _feature_ this site-wide.

Comment: @5chdn thanks...there's still plenty of room for improvement...

Answer (score 6):

## Getting started

- [What are the Ethereum disk space needs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/143/87)
- [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/108/87)
- [How can I recover or reset a lost wallet password?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/97/87)
- [How long does it take for the ethereum blockchain to synchronize?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1312/87)
- [Ethereum Node Stuck, Can't Sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2746/87)
- [How do I buy Ethereum with USD?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1915/87)
- [What is the recommended way to safely store Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1239/87)

Answer (score 5):

## What is Ethereum

- [How would I explain Ethereum to a non-technical friend?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/45/87)
- [What are the differences between Bitcoin blockchain and Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/700/87)
- [What is the total supply of Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/443/87)
- [How does Lisk differ from Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2104/87)
- [What's the difference between proof of stake and proof of work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/118/87)
- [Why does Ethereum plan to move to Proof of Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9/87)
- [What is "gas" and transaction fee in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-gas-and-transaction-fee-in-ethereum)
- [What is an uncle/ommer block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-an-uncle-ommer-block)
- [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)
- [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)
- [What is a DApp?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/383/what-is-a-dapp)
- [Why don't Ethereum addresses have checksums?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/267/why-dont-ethereum-addresses-have-checksums)

Answer (score 4):

## Mining (Proof of Work)

- [What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2719/87)
- [How to Mine Ether and use Ethereum on Windows?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/110/87)
- [What are some good mining pools?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1532/87)
- [How do I check my mining hashrate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1586/87)
- [When will the difficulty bomb make mining impossible?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3779/87)
- [How to mine Ether on GNU + Linux?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/111/87)
- [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2325/87)
- [What is the current DAG size? When do we expect to hit GPU limits?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/426/87)
- [Why is the average block time 17 seconds?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58/why-is-the-average-block-time-17-seconds)

[proof-of-work](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-work)[mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining)[mining-pools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-pools)

Answer (score 3):

## Contract Development

- [Where can I find some Solidity / Smart Contract source code examples?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2940/87)
- [How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3514/87)
- [Upgradeable smart contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2404/820)
- [How can I securely generate a random number in my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-i-securely-generate-a-random-number-in-my-smart-contract)
- [Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)
- [How can an Ethereum contract get data from a website?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-get-data-from-a-website)
- [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time)
- [Is there anything stopping me from using the ethereum blockchain as data storage?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/444/is-there-anything-stopping-me-from-using-the-ethereum-blockchain-as-data-storage)
- [What is a recursive calling vulnerability?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6176/what-is-a-recursive-calling-vulnerability)
- [What OPCODES are available for the Ethereum EVM?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119/what-opcodes-are-available-for-the-ethereum-evm)
- [Is it a good practice to log an event every time I throw in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/is-it-a-good-practice-to-log-an-event-every-time-i-throw-in-solidity)

[contract-development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-development)[contract-debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-debugging)[contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design)[events](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events)[evm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evm)

#### High Level Languages

[serpent](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serpent)[solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solidity)[lll](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lll)

#### Compilers

[compilation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation)[browser-solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser-solidity)[solc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solc)

## Contract Interface Development

- [What is an ABI and why is it needed to interact with contracts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts)
- [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)
- [How to get contract internal transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/how-to-get-contract-internal-transactions)
- [Is it a good practice to log an event every time I throw in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/is-it-a-good-practice-to-log-an-event-every-time-i-throw-in-solidity)
- [How do I parse the transaction receipt log with web3.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/how-do-i-parse-the-transaction-receipt-log-with-web3-js)
- [How to call a contract method using the eth_call JSON-RPC API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-call-a-contract-method-using-the-eth-call-json-rpc-api)

[abi](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abi)[web3js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web3js)[json-rpc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json-rpc)

Answer (score 3):

## Clients and UX

- [Help with very slow mist sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/603/87)
- [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1161/87)
- [How to import a plain private key into geth or Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/465/87)
- [How to backup mist wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/946/87)
- [How can I get a geth node to download the blockchain quickly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/392/87)
- [How to delete or reset the blockchain in geth? (OSX)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1897/87)
- [What's the advantage of EthOS over Ubuntu or Windows mining?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2316/87)
- [Where can I download the Mist browser? (NOT the Ethereum wallet)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2140/87)
- [Common useful JavaScript snippets for geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth)

#### Clients:

[go-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum)[parity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity)[pyethapp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyethapp)

#### GUIs:

[metamask](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metamask)[mist](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mist)[parity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parity)

Answer (score 1):

## Proof of Stake

- [How does the Casper proof of stake algorithm work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/102/87)
- [When will Ethereum switch to Proof of Stake so miners can plan to prepare themselves?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1922/87)
- [Why does Ethereum plan to move to Proof of Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9/87)
- [What's the difference between proof of stake and proof of work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118/whats-the-difference-between-proof-of-stake-and-proof-of-work)

[proof-of-stake](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-stake)

Answer (score 1):

## Systems built on/with/around Ethereum

#### Ethereum Name Service

*A distributed, extensible naming system based on the Ethereum blockchain.*

- [Is it possible to get a list of all active auctions on ENS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-all-active-auctions-on-ens)
- [How can I bid in an ENS auction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15887/how-can-i-bid-in-an-ens-auction)

[ens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ens)

#### File Retrieval: IPFS, Storj and Swarm

- [What is the difference between Swarm and IPFS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2138/87)
- [What is Swarm and what is it used for?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/375/87)
- [How can I store big files on the blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/how-can-i-store-big-files-on-the-blockchain)
- [How to access files hosted on swarm?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3826/how-to-access-files-hosted-on-swarm)
- [How to add a file to IPFS using the API?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/how-to-add-a-file-to-ipfs-using-the-api)

[ipfs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipfs)[swarm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swarm)[storj](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storj)

#### The "The DAO"

- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/7204/87)
- [How to withdraw Ether from The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3748/87)
- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/8338/87)
- [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/7265/87)

[the-dao](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-dao)

Answer (score 0):

## Testing

#### Simulated Node

[testrpc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testrpc)

#### Private Testnet

- [How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/125/87)

[private-blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/private-blockchain)

#### Public Testnet

[testnets](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testnets)